# What does "new (&variable) value;" in C++ do?

Tags: c++, operators, new-operator

Say I have the following code in a C++ program:

```
Object a = Object(someParameters);
new (&a) Object(someOtherParameters);
```

My assumption is that it replaces the contents of `a` with `Object(someOtherParameters)`, avoiding a possible `operator=` declared for `Object`. Is this correct?

Comment: As an aside to the existing answers: the syntax in the *title* of your question doesn’t exist! You cannot use this syntax with any value, you can just use it in a constructor call – i.e. `value` must be of the form `T(arguments)`.

Comment: placement new always used in a C++ memory pool(objects pool). as additional reply.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's called [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). It calles the constructor on the specified memory rather than allocating new memory. Note that in this case you have to explicitly call the destructor of your object before freeing the allocated memory.

Clarification. Suppose you have allocated some raw memory

```
char * rawMemory = new char [sizeof (Object)];
```

and you want to construct an object on that memory. You call

```
new(rawMemory) Object(params);
```

Now, before freeing the memory

```
delete [] rawMemory;
```

you will have to call the derstuctor of Object explicitly

```
reinterpret_cast<Object*>(rawMemory)->~Object();
```

In your particular example, however, the potential problem is that you haven't properly destroyed the existing object before constructing a new one in its memory.

**Bonus:**
Ever wondered how standard `std::vector` can do without its contained objects being default-constructible? The reason is that on most, if not all, implementations `allocator<T>` does not store a `T* p` which would require T to be default-constructible in case of `p = new T[N]`. Instead it stores a `char` pointer - raw memory, and allocates `p = new char[N*sizeof(T)]`. When you `push_back` an object, it just calls the copy constructor with placement new on the appropriate address in that char array.

Comment: The last sentence is confusing / wrong: The destructor is automatically called at the end of the scope before the object’s memory is freed. But the destructor for the *previously existing* object has to be called before overwriting it. For added goodness, this answer should also mention the possibility of overloading the operator – potentially an overload does something completely different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: No, it's not. `Class* object = new (rawMemory) Class(params);` You cannot later call `delete object;` because the memory was no allocated by normal `new`. Therefore, you have to call `object->~Class()` explicitly before calling `delete [] rawMemory`.

Comment: The object in OP’s question is stack-allocated and of the correct type so your objection doesn’t apply. Even for dynamically allocated memory, you can very well do the following: `T* x = new T; x->~T(); new (x) T(); delete x;` (note the order of destructor call and placement new!)

Comment: Both the answer and Konrad's comment fail to address that it is perfectly fine (according to the standard, good luck in a code review) not to call the destructor if the program does not depend on the side effects of the destructor, both for the old object before calling placement new and the new object.

Comment: The **Bonus** section is *wrong*/imprecise. Most implementations do hold `T*`, although not obtained with `new T[]`. The container tracks how much of the memory allocated and pointed by that `T*` corresponds to actual `T` objects and how much it is uninitialized.

Answer (score 6):

It's known as **placement new**: it constructs the new `Object` at the address given inside the parentheses. Placement new is usually used to create an object in raw memory. Constructing a new object on top of an existing one, as this code does, is a bad idea, because it doesn't call the destructor on the original object.